# PolynomialGCD::lrgexp when integrating

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I want to calculate the exponential in the last line of the following code, but the code never completes and just produces errors about `PolynomialGCD`.

```
RadiusEarth = 6371*10^3;
RadiusSphere = 6871*10^3;
Rmax = Sqrt[RadiusSphere^2 - RadiusEarth^2];
Rmin = RadiusSphere - RadiusEarth;
LoSpathloss = 3;
NLoSpathloss = 4;
pLoS[v_] = 
 Exp[-1*Cot[
    ArcSin[(RadiusSphere^2 - RadiusEarth^2)/(2*RadiusEarth*v) - 
      v/(2*RadiusEarth)]]]
StrongFunction[v_] = 
 v*(1 - (pLoS[
       v]/(1 + (k*v^(-LoSpathloss)/2)^2)) - ((1 - pLoS[v])/(1 + 
        k*v^(-NLoSpathloss))))

Exp[-2*\[Pi]*10/2/\[Pi]/(RadiusSphere)/(RadiusSphere - RadiusEarth)*
  RadiusSphere/RadiusEarth*\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(Rmin\), \
\(Rmax\)]\(StrongFunction[v] \[DifferentialD]v\)\)]
```

> PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.

Can someone help me identify the problem with my code?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code with your post that can be copied, pasted and executed in our notebook sessions. You can copy directly from the input cell, press Edit under your post and paste the code at the correct location. There is a { ... } icon to format it as code. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for advice! I saved it as text and changed it. I didn't know I can save it as coding format.

Comment: your integral does not evaluate for me.  When you have a problem, try smaller steps. Just do the integration on its own., I am on V 13.2 now.  Your integral is the problem. Try numerical integration for some k values and you see it gives errors there also.

Comment: I'm on V 13.3, but regardless of version I think my code has problem since I'm not very familiar with it... Thanks for advice. I think I have to try some modification..

Comment: It gives the same error for me very quickly when  using `Assumptions -> k > 0`  Try this for very fast response: `Integrate[StrongFunction[v], {v, Rmin, Rmax}, Assumptions -> k > 0, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]`  it returns unevaluated,. same for `k<0`. This shows the integral can't be evaluated. Not all integrals can be evaluated.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoROd.png)

Comment: Thank you for reply! I'll change all the codes and try again. I appreciate your help.

Comment: $k$ is not defined.  Also suggest you use numerical integration via the `NIntegrate[StrongFunction[v],{v,vStart,vEnd}]` once you assign a value for $k$and then just confirm it works for small limits first.  Otherwise, the integrand looks pretty tough to integrate with $k$ as unassigned constant.

Comment: @josh I already tried numerical integration as I mentioned above for few random k value. They all give zero but with warnings  `NIntegrate::izero`  If this integral came from physical problem, then something is wrong in the model.

Comment: @Nasser:  The integral is very small (complex-valued) for small integral range and $k=1$.  For example `NIntegrate[StrongFunction[v] /. k -> 1, {v, 100, 111}]` is on the order of about $10^{-6}$.  Are we sure it's zero for the range above or just too small to be calculated?

Comment: There is something wrong with `StrongFunction`.  `StrongFunction[Rmax]` produces a 1/0 error.